# Mapping a Java "null" in Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, json, null

Today I was returning a JSON String from Java to Objective-c. It outputted a `null`. To check for the Java `null` in objective-c I can use `KCFNULL` which is a typdef to some struct (as far as I can remember).

The question here is how to map Java's `null` to Objective-C's `KCFNULL`?

Comment: you better to find where you read that!

Comment: @Muhammad: I reformulated the question. Tell me if it fits what you're looking for.

Comment: I've found more than one post useful.. Although, I cannot find one that 100% answer me... so I cannot decide which one to choose

Answer (score 4):

There is none.

`null` is `null` -- it is the only value of Object which represents "no object". This differs from C/C++ where NULL is a #define for `(void*)0` (which generally means 0) or similar.

In addition, Java strings are *not* NUL-terminated (note [NUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), the NULL *character* -- and not "NULL"!). Rather, they are stored with an explicit length like C++'s `std::string`. (NUL is 0 in ASCII and Unicode, thus `(char)0` represents NUL.)

Happy coding.

Comment: Well, I am agree with you.. but Today I was returning a json string from Java to Objective-c which contains `null` and to check for the `java null` in objective-c I used KCFNULL which is a typdef to something else, the question here how Objc represents the KCFULL???

Comment: @Muhammad See [CFNull](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNullRef/Reference/reference.html). Note that is a special object (not `nil`!) that represents "no value". .NET has a similar DbNull type which represents "no value" in a specific context. Consider updating the question with code that pertains to *what* is actually being done. Note that any mapping of `null` to `CFNull` (or `nil` or whatever it may be) is done in said language-binding layer. Perhaps you mean to have Objective-C load JSON's "null" as `kCFNull`?

Comment: @Muhammad I am too! Consider updating the post with sample code showing the exact problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The `null` value in Java has nothing to do with ASCII or any character set.

If you're trying to represent the ASCII null character in Java, it's `'\u0000'`

Comment: Maybe he's talking about the C Null-character, `\0`?

Answer (score 0):

Null is not an object in that represents the absence of the latter. It will print out as null in the console despite the lack of a toString method. However to get an ASCII value you'd need to cast it to char/Character first and the chances are that the compiler will refuse this. So the short answer is that there is no ASCII equivalent for null in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps thinking of the null *character* `"like\0this"` in a string constant (which has nothing to do with the `null` keyword, just to prevent misunderstandings)?

That one is really zero, also known as U+0000 or `(char)0`, and identical to ASCII's NUL.

What you *may* be remembering is that the *internal* representation of string constants inside a `.class` file uses a "modified UTF-8" encoding which represents all ASCII characters as bytes with the ASCII value -- *except* the null character, which is represented as the two-byte combination `0xC0 0x80`. That is, however an implementation detail, solely a matter between the bytecode compiler and the JVM, and it should not be visible to the programmer at all.

Comment: So, can I consider `0xC0 0x80` is the null `jvm-internal` representation?

Comment: @Muhammad, I'm don't really understand what you're doing, but _probably_ it doesn't mean whatever you think it means. It is simply a feature of the file format, and for all intents and purposes **has no significance at all** for how a program behaves. In particular, it has absolutely nothing to do with JSON serialization.

Comment: really confused! can you point me where to start to understand this topic?

Comment: It now sounds to me like your problem has nothing at all to do with Java (and nothing to do with ASCII either), but is purely a question of how your JSON parser on the Objective-C side represents JSON's "null" construct.

Comment: @Muhammad: Read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode. Henning Makholm is talking about the binary contents of a class file. In other words the bytecode that has been produced after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, we have "`Nil`", "`nil`, and "`null`".  They are all zero, but their types differ.  `Nil` is a Class pointer, `nil`is an object pointer, and `null` is a `void *`.  There is also the `NSNull` class, which can represent a null value in collections like `NSArray`.